# .NET Correct Task use

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am new to .NET Tasks and async coding so I would just like to know what I should do in my case:

I have a .NET Core WebApi that receives a XML file, which acts as the trigger for the following process:

1. I need the process to run in the "background", so what I mean is the API caller should get a response immediatly and the process should then run
2. I need to parse the XML to an object
3. With this data, I need to contact 3 APIs
4. If any of this APIs do not respond or fails to retrieve the needed data, we need to stop and log this
5. If all of the data is retrieved, I need to do a calculation with this data (get some data from a database and calculate with the API & database data)
6. When calculation is done, I need to send an email and contact another API

   **7. And the most important: Am I safe with this, due to the AppRecycle ?**

This was just to explain my situation, so what I have is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> DepositAsync([FromBody] Taa message){
try
{
    Api1Response api1Response = await this.GetApiData1();
    Api1Response api2Response = await this.GetApiData2();

    // If all of this was successful, do the calculation
    CalculationResult result = await this.CalculateAsync(api1Response, api2Response);

    // Notify 
    await Notify(result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error($"Something went wrong: {ex.Message}", ex);
    throw;
}


return new JsonResult(new ApiResponse<string>(requestId.ToString(), Response, StatusCodes.Status200OK) { Data = "Success" });
}
```

The question that I have now:

1. When do I need to use Task.Run(() => {}); Inside of the GetApiData1(), GetApiData2() methods, to do the Http call ?
2. Do I need call teh GetApi methods inside a Task.Run(() => {}); ?
3. In general, when do I need to use Task.Run and when not ?

Or do I just need to do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> DepositAsync([FromBody] Taa message){
try
{
    Task.Run(() => {
        Api1Response api1Response = await this.GetApiData1();
        Api1Response api2Response = await this.GetApiData2();

        // If all of this was successful, do the calculation
        CalculationResult result = await this.CalculateAsync(api1Response, api2Response);

        // Notify 
        await Notify(result);
    });  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error($"Something went wrong: {ex.Message}", ex);
    throw;
}


return new JsonResult(new ApiResponse<string>(requestId.ToString(), Response, StatusCodes.Status200OK) { Data = "Success" });
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct that you can use `Task.Run` without `await` to "offload" some work to another thread from the `ThreadPool`. While doing that, your request's response time will not be affected by the work which is done inside of it.

However, any exception which happens inside of that function will not be thrown to the *caller* thread (since call is not awaited). That effectively means your try-catch block will only catch exceptions which happen when new `Task` is created (by `Task.Run` method). In other words, it will not catch any error which happens while processing lambda passed to the `Task.Run` method.

So, in your case the second approach would be correct (with mentioned downsides above). 
In addition,  IIS will wait for running threads to finish and exit *on recycling*, limited by the timeout set on the thread pool. So, if execution is larger than the timeout, thread will be forcibly killed.

Lastly, in .Net Core new type of services are introduced, they are called Hosted services and implement [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). They are built to support these kind of long running background tasks. You can get familiar with them via official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), and that would be my recommendation to use.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just have 2 more questions:
- Can I use either Task.Run or IHostedService for this purpose ?
- With Task.Run is it possible that the Tasks will be recycled?

Comment: Or at what point should I use IHostedService and when should I take Task.Run ?

Comment: And should I wrap the method call with Task.Run or should I use Task.Run inside the method ?